# MySql. 'group by' by parts

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

there is a table

CREATE TABLE `geography_schedule` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `geography_address_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `geography_city_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `sort` int(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '500',
  `site` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'site',
  `group_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `day` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `all_day` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `freeday` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `from` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '09:00',
  `to` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '18:00',
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `timestamp_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `geography_schedule` (`from`, `to`, `geography_address_id`, `day_from`, `day_to`, `group_id`) VALUES
('09:00', '18:00', 533, 1, 1, 1),
('09:00', '18:00', 533, 2, 2, 1),
('11:00', '17:00', 533, 3, 3, 1),
('11:00', '17:00', 533, 4, 4, 1),
('09:00', '18:00', 533, 5, 5, 1),
('10:00', '17:00', 533, 6, 6, 1),
('09:00', '18:00', 533, 7, 7, 1);

I have a mysql query from this table [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr54d.jpg)

```
SELECT `from`,`to`, `geography_address_id`, MIN(`day`) as `day_from`
 ,MAX(`day`)  as  `day_to`,`group_id`  
FROM `geography_schedule` 
WHERE `geography_address_id` = 533 
GROUP BY `from`,`to` 
ORDER BY `geography_schedule`.`day` ASC
```

result:

[image: current result]

I need to group by lines 9:00 - 18:00 to save days `day_from` & `day_to` in proper order.

Is it possible to use GROUP BY in such a way it will give the result like this?

[image: required output]

Comment: So the first entry 09:00 - 18:00 1-7 is a default that applies to any day not represented by an actual day_from day_to? In which case why aren't there 2 entries in your desired output 09:00 - 18:00 day_from = 1 day_to = 1 and 09:00 - 18:00 day_from = 2 day_to = 2?

Comment: Can you add sample data from `geography_schedule` as text to your question

Comment: hello! i updated my question

Comment: The create table doe not syntax probably because of day,from,to not being escaped and There are more fields expected than provided in the insert statement.